# c++ created socket value is very large like 590258032 etc

Tags: sockets

I'm using the following code to create sockets with [UTD](http://udt.sourceforge.net/), but I get very large values that exceed the limits of `int`.

```
int m_bindsock = UDT::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)
```

Please advise what could be wrong in the environment/code to fix this. I am on Ubuntu 14, and trying to create UDP sockets.

Comment: You'll need to look in the UDT source code to see what their socket() function is doing internally.  Presumably it calls through to the BSD socket API's socket() function with the same arguments; in which case either the BSD socket() function is returning a strange value (which seems unlikely), or UDT::socket() isn't returning the value properly.  Or a third possibility:  the returned value is okay, but whatever code/debugger you are using the examine the value is printing it out incorrectly.

Comment: Btw if the value you are seeing really is bigger than what an int can actually hold, that's a strong clue that the values you are seeing is not the actual value being held by the int, and that it is your printing-method that is at fault.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner "*Presumably it calls through to the BSD socket API's socket() function with the same arguments*" - actually, (in v4 anyway) `UDT::socket()` returns a `UDTSOCKET` (a typedef for `int`) that is a key into an internal `std::map` of `CUDTSocket*` object pointers. The IDs start at `1 + (int)((1 << 30) * (double(rand()) / RAND_MAX))` and get decremented with each new "socket" that is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UDT::socket()` function [returns a `UDTSOCKET`-type value](http://udt.sourceforge.net/udt4/doc/socket.htm) - and `UDTSOCKET` is apparently an `int`, so there shouldn't be any overflow. Regardless - define `m_bindsock` to be a `UDTSOCKET`, not an `int`.

Now, on failure, `UDT::socket()` it returns `UDT::INVALID_SOCK`, so maybe you should just compare against that, and/or see what [`getlasterror()`](http://udt.sourceforge.net/udt4/doc/error.htm) tells you.

Comment: Thanks, the error was that I was passing the type as SOCK_STREAM instead of SOCK_DGRAM